# Power Transformation for Rainfall bias Correction in R

Tags: r, excel

I am new to R and trying to bias correct the satellite rainfall data and currently, I am using a spreadsheet available at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301625702_Power_Transformation_V20_Microsoft_Excel_file. Which uses a 90 day window period but I want to do it using multiple window periods so how do I perform this task in R.

The core equation used in the above excel file is

```
                  a.P^b
```

where  P is precipitation and b is such that

```
                  f(b)= 0 =covariance(Observe)-Covariance(Satellite^b)
```

we have to compute the value of b iteratively for each group of data in a selected window period considering daily rainfall data in a year.

For Example, if I consider 1-year of data (365 days) and window period of 5 days then there will be 73 groups of data, and parameter b needs to be estimated for every 73 groups i.e 73 values for b.

Comment: it would help if you (1) phrased your question as "how do I do this" rather than "is there a tool for this" (this is a web site for programming questions) (2) gave the formula rather than just saying "look at the Excel sheet" and (3) showed what you've tried so far ...

Comment: Dear @BenBolker thanks for your valuable suggestion. I have updated my question as per your suggestions.